# How to bodyParse JSON NodeJS + Express?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, heroku, express

help me im sending `{"simple": "json"}` and i get back `{ }`

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.post('/', function (req, res) {
   console.log(req.body);
   res.json(req.body);
})
```

Comment: Are you actually sending a `Content-Type` of `application/json` ?

Comment: I  ADD application/json in the arduino and it works  =)